# How the Embeded ruby code produces the HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

How the above code Produces the HTML like below ? Please Explain it.

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Welcome to the Sample App!</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking for information about the RoR templating syntax, or how it actually works internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded ruby code does not produces HTMl. It just o/p string which gets embedded into the HTML. Anything within:

```
<%= "text" %>
```

gets into the output.

In your case

```
<div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
```

key variable is a string  "success"

value variable is a string  "Welcome to the Sample App!"

So, value of key variable get substituted with "success" and so on..